# Using hash tags with Facebook share possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fragment-identifier

I'm developing an ajax based web site and I want to include a FB share function on the loaded content. The links use a hash tag and I can't manage to get the full links to show up when using the share function, I only get the domain url. Are hash tags not allowed or is there a special method for sharing such links?

Comment: The text after a `#` in a URI is a **fragment identifier**, not a hash tag. A hashtag is a system to facilitate searching for related content on Twitter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use URL Encoding for the `#` character.  Just replace the following:

```
http://www.example.com/#/path/to/whatever/
```

with:

```
http://www.example.com/%23/path/to/whatever/
```

This will allow you to pass the `#` to share on Facebook, Twitter, etc without getting stripped.

Comment: It does for me! I first replaced the `#` with `%23` and than PHP's `urlencode()` on top.

Comment: Tried to use javascript encodeURIComponent but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Google's answer to the AJAX content problem, [the hashbang](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).

Basically, on your AJAX page, set the hash to `!/path/to/whatever/` – in other words,

```
http://www.example.com/#!/path/to/whatever/
```

Keep in mind your server must actually serve content similar to what you'd see in the AJAX application at `http://www.example.com/path/to/whatever/`.

I'm not sure if Facebook respects the hashbang, but it does at least solve Googlebot problems for you.  **Edit:** It looks like Facebook [doesn't support the hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7933632/201952).  You'll probably have to set up a redirector page.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I saw that thread now, looks like FB doesn't support any type of hash method :(