# Facebook sharer using hashtags and modrewrite

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, facebook-sharer, hashtag

so I am trying to use the facebook sharer to share urls with hashtags.. but i dont need them to be indexed by google crawlers or anything..

The idea is the hashtag is a code for the content on the page (its a random item generator for a game - http://manlysmite.com/)

Anyways, so sharing hash tags doesnt work.. even if i update the opengraph tags AND the sharer url.. now i dont want to use a 'like' button as like i mentioned i dont want to index these pages as individual items..

I found that if you use a '|' (pipe) instead of a '#' (hash) in the url when sharing to facebook it recognises it as a proper url..

my question is, can i use modrewrite rules in .htaccess to changes the '|' to a '#' server side so that when it reaches the page it's a '#'? if so, could someone tell me what i should be putting in the .htaccess file as i cant seem to find 'replace single url character rewrite' information? is this even the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to rewrite the hash since it's a client side thing. Usually the hash isn't sent to the server.

Have you tried this:
[Using hash tags with Facebook share possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610156/using-hash-tags-with-facebook-share-possible)
replace # with %23 when sharing?

Comment: yeah that doesn't work either, it polls the main site for its og details and posts them rather than those at the # address. If you have a facebook account you can try it out :)

Comment: Also, regarding client vs server.. The link would look like http://example.com/|hashtag (which would render server side), its just whether replacing it with a # would actually render client side :)

Comment: if you enter example.com/#hashtag in your browser, example.com will be loaded, and then you can access the #hashtag using javascript, but it will always be example.com and its og details that is rendered first, even if you successfully redirects from i.e example.com/|hashtag. Why do you need the # in the url?

Comment: im using the # in the url to create unique codes for each of the 'rolls' of the randomiser (i dont want to refresh the page but want to change the url).. and want people to be able to link back to that roll later.. if i use example.com/|hashtag (as this is seen as a page, not a hashtag) facebook sharer will fail to scrape any og data and use the passed title and url data

Comment: I would probably create the url:s like example.com/353dfaafsd and then use example.com/#353dfaafsd for those browsers, like IE to be able to update the URL (in HTML5 browsers you can update the URL without #). And then use the example.com/353dfaafsd as the facebook share URL.

Comment: And have example.com/#353dfaafsd to render example.com/353dfaafsd via javascript. Like twitter does with their https://twitter.com/#!/username and https://twitter.com/username URLs

Comment: would you have any links to how to achieve this? jquery plugin? :) thanks for all your help

Comment: I've not done exactly what you are doing, but I have been updating URLs in browsers using History.js: https://github.com/balupton/History.js/