# Share a link with hash on Facebook sharer not possible

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to share a link on Facebook, the link is like below:

`http://mydomain.com/mypath#photos:para=a&para2=b`

but without luck, the result is:
`http://mydomain.com/mypath`
which is not what I want, I try below link:

[Using hash tags with Facebook share possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610156/using-hash-tags-with-facebook-share-possible)

to replace the `#` with `%23` but then it gives me:`http://127.0.0.1/mypath?photos%3Apara=a` which is obvious wrong.

Any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

BTW the facebook sharer link is:

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={0}`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook wont crawl the Javascript.

But as Facebook take the og tag into the account.

So you need to create pages alike your hash pages with different URL.

May be http://mydomain.com/mypath?para=a&para2=b

for : http://mydomain.com/mypath#photos:para=a&para2=b

And place only og metas in there, and redirect the page with Javascript. You may also put same data as in the hash page.

So Facebook will read the og tags. And if the link is clicked on Facebook than it will redirect after page load.

Thanks