# Sharing via open graph along with hash tags

Tags: share, facebook-opengraph, hashtag

I have implemented share buttons for different social networks, such as VK, Facebook, Twitter, OK, and I am using Open Graph to set attributes of post, that will occur at user's social network page.

I'd like to add hash tag to the post shared, in order to let the user see it on his social network page and use then, i.e. filter content of social network by this tag.

(Just to clarify: the tag should be only in a social network, my website doesn't have hash tags at all)

I've found [how to add hash tags to urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610156/using-hash-tags-with-facebook-share-possible) but my problem seems to be different a bit.

I didn't find special Open Graph attribute for it, nor I found same in Twitter Card.

Where should I put my hash tags? Would `og:description` be appropriate for it?

Comment: you can add it to the description in twitter, but you can't alter the message or add hashtags in facebook

Comment: @Mousey, is it possible to suggest message for user, but let him decide what to do with it? Or is it impossible at all?

Comment: that's not allowed by facebook but is allowed by twitter (for example suggesting they include your twitter handle or hashtags). Robin Pierrot's answer gives the exact wording from facebook. Can you customize the desciption of the link only (which the user can't edit -  but which is seen by everyone they send the link to). Given that this is called a prefill violation by facebook I would not expect any workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://wpsocial.com/facebook-introduces-hashtags-how-you-can-use-this-for-your-business-now/) it is not possible to do this via meta tags:

> My test was adding hashtags to the Open Graph Meta Data.
>
> ... the custom description and hash tags did absolutely nothing

I have checked them all as well.

**It's impossible to insert hash tags in**:

1. Facebook
2. Ok

**There are two exceptions**:

3. VK derives user the user's message from the title (in case user left it blank), so if the title contains a hash tag, the last one will finally turn into link and work

E.g.:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My website #mywebsite">
```

4. Twitter accepts hash tags inside share button `href` attribute as a parameter `text`

E.g.:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com&text=«Example»%20%23example"></a>
```

Add the `#example` hash tag to parameter `text` :

```
text=«Example»%20%23example
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want to prefill the user's message on the share dialog, right ?

If so, you can't, according to the policy of Facebook : 
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

and

> × Add your own content to that which the user manually entered. This includes hashtags, hyperlinks or URLs.

Look here, I think you want to do is the *Prefill Violation Example Two*
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: Actually, I didn't think about adding content to a user's fields. I thought that adding hash tags into the Open Graph meta tags would solve the problem, but it didn't help as well

Comment: Yes, my purpose was *example two* :-)

Comment: I haven't checked this yet, but I still hope I am able to suggest message to user